# Forcing to re-apply a style sheet in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Consider this HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
</ul>
```

This CSS:

```
li:first-child { background: yellow; }
```

And this Javascript (jQuery):

```
$("ul").append($("li:first-child"));
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Xtuaf/

Apparently in **Internet Explorer** (8) `:first-child` breaks when the DOM has changed. I wrote a workaround for this problem in Javascript (doing styling there; `z-index`es in my case). It's an ugly quick fix that I want to get rid of. A better solution would be forcing to re-apply the style sheet when the DOM changes. Can this be done? Or is there an other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, a reflow can be triggered by setting the class name:

```
$("ul").append($("li:first-child")).addClass('x').removeClass('x');
```

Or just (demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Xtuaf/1/):

```
$("ul").append($("li:first-child"))[0].className += '';
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to reliably cause a reflow of the entire DOM is to quick add and remove an arbitrary class from the body element.

```
$('body').addClass('foo').removeClass('foo');
```