# Need separate javascript file function to work and it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a unique problem that I hope someone can help with.  I have a page that pulls data from a controller with AJAX and presents it to this function to construct a table:

```
     // make rows in table from json data
function makeTableRows() {
    if (jsonTableData != null) {
        tbl = null;
        tbl = createTable('tableResults');
        //            constructHeader(tbl, 'left', jsonTableData[0]);
        newHeader(tbl, 'left', jsonTableData[0]);
        var totalItems = jsonTableData.length;
        var topItem;
        topItem = 0;
        if ((lastItem + perpage) > totalItems) {
            topItem = totalItems;
            $(".btnNext").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            topItem = lastItem + perpage;
        }
        for (var i = lastItem; i <= topItem - 1; i++) {
            makeTableRow(tbl, jsonTableData[i], 'left', true, 'showTourDetails(' + jsonTableData[i]["TransactionID"] + ',' + i + ')', 0);
        }

        $("#divSearchResults").html(tbl);
        makePagesLabel();
        makeTableFooter(tbl);
    }
}
```

the function inside the separate file is this:

```
 function constructHeader(table, alignment, firstRow) {
  if (firstRow != null) {
    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    table.appendChild(thead);
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var key in firstRow) {
        var header = key.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g);
        var newHeader = '';
        for (var i = 0; i <= header.length - 1; i++) {
            newHeader += header[i] + ' ';
        }
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        var text = document.createTextNode(newHeader);
        th.appendChild(text);
        th.style.textAlign = alignment;
        th.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        th.setAttribute('title', "Sort by " + newHeader);
        th.onclick = function () {
            var rows = $(table).find('tbody').find('tr').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
            this.asc = !this.asc;
            if (!this.asc) {
                rows = rows.reverse();
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                $(table).append(rows[j]);
            }
            $(table).find('tbody').find('tr:even').css("background-color", "#dae5f4");
                $(table).find('tbody').find('tr:odd').css("background-color", "#b8d1f3");
        };
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    thead.appendChild(tr);
 }
}
```

Basically the function creates a sort process for the header of each column.  After the sort of the column, I want to reapply the zebra striping that is applied with the class of the table.  If I don't try to reapply I end up with the striping all messed up.  Now, the problem is that if I copy the function into the .cshtml page and give it the name of 'newheader', the re-striping works fine.  It does not work in the separate JS file and I cannot figure out why.  Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Why are you applying css to each row individually for zebra striping? Just do it once in a CSS header: `tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}


tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}`

Comment: The table class applies the striping when first loaded.  I'm trying to re-stripe it when it is sorted.  It works either way, but does not work in a separate js file.  That is the question...

Comment: Jonathan's solution means you don't have to stripe it at all in any javascript location, even after resorting the table.

Comment: I have this in the .css file included with the page: .table_body thead tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #b8d1f3; }.  So when the table is loaded it is nicely stripped.  When I sort the striping changes and is all screwed up.  I am rewriting the table rows like I show above and the color follows the row.  How do I do it then?

Comment: @JonathanM - I understand what you are saying and the CSS works fine when I first load the table.  After the table is sorted, the original color follows the row and it is not restripped.  Why not?

Comment: Per the second answer in this link, adding and removing an arbitrary class will cause the entire DOM to re-flow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936881/forcing-to-re-apply-a-style-sheet-in-ie